# How to form the equation of a line from a gradient?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am given that the gradient of a curve is $dy / dx = 10x^4 - 6x^2 + 5 $ And I need to find the equation of the curve.

I started by integrating this (as it is the reverse of differentiation) and got

$ y = 2x^5 - 2x^3 + 5x$

which is all right except the answers say there should be a $ -1$ at the end, and I can't understand where that comes from.

I have a core 1 exam tomorrow, so help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to include the constant of integration in you integration. The general form of your desired curve is given by

$$y = 2x^5 - 2x^3 + 5x + C$$

I suspect you have been given a point on the curve $(x_0, y_0)$,  which you can use to solve for that constant of integration, $C$.

EDIT:

From the comment below, the curve does indeed pass through a given point $(1, 4)$.

$$y = 2x^5 - 2x^3 + 5x + C \implies 4 = 2 - 2 +5 +C \iff C = -1$$

Comment: Yeah, you're right, forgot to put that in, it passes through (1, 4)

Comment: Then you simply plug is $x = 1$, $y = 4$, and solve for $C$.

Comment: Ah thanks very much, really helpful :D

Comment: You're welcome!